# Change the order of email accounts in iOS

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

I'm curious if there is a way to re-order email accounts in Mail on iOS without re-setting all the accounts up (I haven't tested re-creating all the accounts). I know someone that has a ton of email accounts on his iPhone, and he would like to re-order them - ones he uses most at the top, with the other further down the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Good question. I've wondered this myself. Unlike lots of other iOS controls, you can't seem to edit the list of accounts by "grabbing" them and moving them around

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since iOS 6, you can re-order mail accounts in the Mail app by pressing <kbd>Edit</kbd> at the Mailboxes screen, and dragging to rearrange.

They should have had this option from the start.

Comment: Still works in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the order of the accounts in iOS 5 or earlier.

I'm afraid you will need to delete them and recreate them if you don't want to (or cannot) upgrade to iOS 6.

There is an edit button in Mail, but all it allows you to do is Delete/Edit Mailboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping someone else would chime in with a hack, but that obviously hasn't happened. Have you confirmed that deleting the email accounts out, then adding them in the order that you would like them works?

Comment: I've done it on my iPad and it worked for me.

Comment: I've just done this on an iPhone5 and it works OK after deletion and then re-adding the account as well - even on iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

To complete previous answers, you need to collapse the account mailboxes so that the drag icon appears next to them. If they are expanded (showing folders like Inbox, Sent, etc.) then you can't reorder them. The order of the mailboxes (just below "All Inboxes") can be different from the order of the accounts listed below.